# How does scope work in Webpack with CommonJS

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs

Maybe this isn't specific to the CommonJS implementation of JS modules, but my question is about how scope works with importing a module.

**CommonnJS: foo.js**

```
var foo = {
  bar() {
      baz();
  }
}

module.exports = foo;
```

**Main JS**

```
const foo = require('./foo.js');

function baz() {
  console.log('this is baz');
}

foo.bar();
//-> ReferenceError: baz is not defined
```

Normally I would expect baz to have been found, but it seems like the module scope is completely isolated. Is that correct? Is there a way or a best practice in what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with webpack.

javascript modules only have local context

If you want something to be a part of the global/window context you can use the `global` variable

```
global.baz = baz;
```

Or better, use dependency injection to pass your callbacks:

```
var foo = {
  bar(baz) {
      baz();
  }
}
```

Then can use it:

```
foo.bar(baz);
```

Comment: I thought it might not have anything to do with webpack, but I thought I'd include it just to be safe.

Dependency injection definitely seems to be the way to go here, thanks for the help :).

Comment: Happy to help :-)